# Algorithm to add sum of every possible xor-sum sub-array

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I participated in one algorithmic competition. I got stuck in one problem, I am asking the same here.

**Problem Statement**

XOR-sum of a sub-array is to XOR all the numbers of that sub-array.
An array is given to you, you have to add all possible such XOR-sub-array.

**Example**

**Input**

Array :- 1 2

**Output** :- 6

**Explanation**

F(1, 1) = A[1] = 1, F(2, 2) = A[2] = 2 and F(1, 2) = A[1] XOR A[2] = 1 XOR 2 = 3. Hence the answer is 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.

I found an $O(N^2)$ solution, but it was too inefficient one and wasn't accepted in the competition.

I saw the best solution of this problem [on Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com/viewplaintext/2928504). But in this code, I didn't understand below module, please help me to understand that.

```
for (int i=0, p=1; i<30; i++, p<<=1) {
    int c=0;
    for (int j=0; j<=N; j++) {
        if (A[j]&p) c++;
    }
    ret+=(long long)c*(N-c+1)*p;
}
```

In pseudocode:

- Set $r = 0$
- For $i$ from $0$ to $29$, let $p = 2^i$.

  - Set $c=0$
  - Iterate over the array $A$. For each element $A[j]$:

    - If $A[j] \mathbin\& p \ne 0$ then increment $c$. ($\&$ is bitwise and.)
  - Add $c \times (N-c+1) \times p$ to $r$

Comment: @D.W. I just want help. I put lots of time on this. At the end, I got stuck. Please help me to put out from here,

Comment: @D.W. If you can, shift this question to SO.

Comment: @devsda There's an answer which explains the algorithm, and it uses mathematical formatting. I don't think this question needs to be migrated, and the answer can't be. If you need help with the code part, ask on [so].

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712487/finding-xor-of-all-subsets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first couple of lines the array $A$ contains the XOR of every prefix of the input numbers in binary. So a $1$ bit at position $k$ in $A[j]$ tells us that there are an odd number of input numbers in the range $0...j$ with $1$ at their position $k= \log p$.

For every $i,j$ s.t. $i \leq j$, if the $k$th bit of $A[i-1]$ is $1$ and the same bit in $A[j]$ is $0$ then there are an odd number of $1$s at bit-position $k$ of the input numbers in the range $i...j$. The same conclusion would be true if the $k$th bit was $0$ for $A[i-1]$ and $1$ for $A[j]$. Please observe that these are the only two situations where the number of ones at position $k$ is odd in the range $i...j$.

Therefore the number of pairs $(A^k[i-1],A^k[j])=(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ is equal to the number of ranges in the input such that their XOR at position $k$ is $1$. Every such range contributes $p=2^k$ to the total sum. In that code, $c$ is the number of ones and $(N-c)$ is the number of zeros at position $k = \log p$. The "$+1$" is to count for the ranges of length one and a $1$ in their $k$th position.

Comment: Then , why i only moves upto 30, Any logic ?

Comment: Can you please explain the whole logic ? How this logic comes in mind, as I am naive.

Comment: It'll help to start with an example of one bit numbers and see what really happens. Then extend it to two bits etc.

Comment: You didn't give my first question's answer.

Comment: ok. Instead of calculating XORs for all possible subarray and then summing them up (which is the naive solution), we count the number of subarrays which $k$th bit of their XOR is 1. This bit adds $2^k$ to the total sum. $c.(N-c)$ is the number of such subarrays. Is it clear now?

Answer (score -1):

Just do the OR operations of all numbers and multiply the answer with power(2,N-1) where N is the length of your array.
For array given in question:
1 OR 2 = 3
Now, 3*(power(2,(2-1))) = 6 which is the answer. 
The point here is that, Each set bit of any number occurs exactly in power(2,N-1) sub arrays.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  The question asks to understand what's going on in a particular solution.  It sounds like you're proposing a different solution.  Would you consider editing your answer to make it clearer how it answers the question that was asked?

Comment: Question line also says that "I participated in one algorithmic competition. I got stuck in one problem, I am asking the same here."